# Django referencing Javascript variable in server side template code

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a page that adds textboxes dynamically, and on the dynamically added text boxes, I want to access the relevant context variable.
To do so, I somehow need to use the 'i' variable inside the javascript code/template code to reference it's value in the context.
Here's my javascript code where I need to use 'i' as an index for a context list:

```
<script>
var i = 2

function add_field()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl_location").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    var input_name = document.createElement("th")
    input_name.appendChild(document.createTextNode("S/N " + i))

    var input_tb = document.createElement("td")
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute("name", "sn" + i);
    {% if curr_sn.i %}
    input.setAttribute("value", {{ curr_sn.i }});
    {% endif %}
    input_tb.appendChild(input)

    var input_row = document.createElement("tr")
    input_row.appendChild(input_name)
    input_row.appendChild(input_tb)

    table.appendChild(input_row);
    i++;
 }
```

The specific lines are:

```
{% if curr_sn.i %}
input.setAttribute("value", {{ curr_sn.i }});
{% endif %}
```

Where 'i' is a javascript veriable, and curr_sn is a list the python code gives as a context.

The html part where I need to use 'i':

```
{% for i in max_board_list %}
    {% if curr_sn.i %}
        <tr>
            <th>S/N {{ i }}</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="sn{{ i }}" value="{{ curr_sn.i }}"></td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here 'i' is generated by a for loop, but I still need to access the same list.

How can I do this in both parts of code? All I could find the the opposite way which already works for me (using django template in javascript code).

Thanks

**EDIT:** for javascript side i found a solution (since I noticed that anyway my code is redundant and tries to do similar things in js&html). For the javascript part I use:

```
{% if curr_sn|length > 1 %}
i = {{ curr_sn|length }}
{% endif %}
```

Just to keep counting from the current number of boards.
Now I need to solve the html parts to display the saved boards in the context variable `curr_sn`

Comment: To be honest I’m having a really hard time understanding your question. Care to elaborate?

Comment: I have a page that can accept a varying number of board names input (default is that 1 row is displayed, and user can add more fields by clicking a button that is linked to the add_field() function. When a user submits the form, in case of a error, I want to keep it's board names in their respective text boxes. My try to do so is by saving the boards names on the python side code within a list that is passed in the context called 'curr_sn'. Back in the html code, I want to check that if a value exists for the current board in the list, I want to display it. Both js&html parts didnt work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for the html part as well. 
I just use custom filters to do the checking.
I've registered two filters:

```
@register.filter(name='is_in')
def is_in(index, list):
    if list is None:
        return False
    try:
        list[int(index)]
        return True
    except:
        return False

 @register.filter(name='get_value')
 def get_value(index, list):
    if list is None:
        return False
    try:
        return list[int(index)]
    except:
        return None
```

And in the HTML part I use the following:

```
{% for i in max_board_list %}
    {% if i|is_in:curr_sn %}
        <tr>
            <th>S/N {{ i }}</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="sn{{ i }}" value="{{ i|get_value:curr_sn }}"></td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this will help for others with the same problem.